# If hands are folded with both index fingers parallel, they will come closer and touch eventually?

Tags: muscles, movement

I have a question out of curiosity. It is just something I found out/discovered:
if I fold my hands into each and let my two index fingers (see picture) be in parallel then they will eventually **come closer to each other and touch**.

How can this be explained?
[image]

---

Another thing I found out: if I fold my fingers on my left hand slightly and then with my right hand squeeze the wrist of my left hand (see picture), then the fingers of the left hand will fold more and more. Is this a coincidence of general?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to explai the first phenomenon is that at rest, your fingers - all of them - curl. Relax on your bed on your back. No matter what direction your hands face, they will curl inward as if loosely holding an egg. That's the anatominal position of the hands at rest, because the finger flexors are stronger than the extendors. So once you set the finfers up, you'll tire of keeping them extended, they'll start  to relax, and in doing so, will tough.

If I'm understanding the second example, that's because the flexor tendons for your fingers are actually in your forearm. Squeeze them and it shortens the tendons causing flexion.

Answer (score 0):

the explanation for the first picture is that this is due to an invisible attraction force which is called (Ideomotor effect) which affects on the left lobe of the brain which permits to our muscles to move involuntary and unawareness.So they will come closer as if they are like a magnet and a nail.